# Does $g$ have a minimum on $X$?

Tags: functions, continuity, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f=\frac{1}{g}$

Suppose $f$ is continuous and not bounded and $g>0$ and that there exists a sequence $u_{n}$ of $X$ such that $g(u_{n})$ converges to zero

Does $g$ have a minimum ?

Comment: What exactly is $X$? A subset of $\Bbb R^n$? A metric space?  A topological space?  An abelian category?

Comment: It is a Metric space

Comment: What do you mean by saying "$g$ has a minimum"? Your $g$ has a greatest lower bound (namely $0$), but does not attain it (i.e., there is no $x$ with $g(x) = 0$).

Comment: Yes I mean the infimum

Comment: Can $X$ be compact ?

Comment: Any set of positive real numbers has an infimum. You need to clarify your question. (In particular, in your context, what does $g > 0$ mean?).

Comment: $g(x)>0$ for all $x$

Comment: Given your clarifications, your question has a lot of redundant detail: any real-valued function $g$ on any set $X$ such that $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in X$ has an infimum. So $f$, continuity and the sequence $u_n$ are all irrelevant. The existence of the $u_n$ tells us what the infimum is, but that isn't what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g>0$ and $g(u_n) \to 0$ then the infimum of $g$ is $0$. Obviously the infimum is not attained.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not necessarily.  For instance, consider the function $f:(0,1)\to \Bbb R$  given by
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}.
$$

Comment: "Not necessarily" requires two examples! The OP needs to give more context before the question can be answered.